# Evaluate $\int_{S}\frac{∂u}{∂n }dS$

Tags: calculus

Let $u$ be a smooth function defined on the ball centered at the origin and
of radius $a > 0$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$
. Assume that $\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}+ \frac{∂^2u}{∂y^2}+\frac{∂^2u}{∂z^2}= 1$
throughout the ball.

Compute:$\int_{S}\frac{∂u}{∂n }dS$

I thinks it will be  zero  because  $S$ is closed surface

Is its true/false ?

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:** Using divergence theorem, we get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Vol}(B_a)=\int_{B_a} dV=\int_{B_a} \Delta u\ dV = \int_{\partial B_a}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\ dS.
\end{align}

Comment: im not  getting  can u elaborate more  in details @Jacky its my humble  request